# How to exclude numbers from a count using Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I can't exclude the number One and Two from my count... I used `whereNotIn` but didn't work, why?

```
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->select(DB::raw('empresa as empresa'), DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
   ->whereNotIn('empresa', ['', 1, 2])
   ->orderBy('number', 'desc')
   ->groupBy('empresa')
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because what you want to exclude is the count result of `empresa`, not `empresa`,

Use `havingRaw()` like this:

```php
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->select(DB::raw('empresa as empresa'), DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
   ->where('empresa', '!=', '')
   ->groupBy('empresa')
   ->havingRaw('number NOT IN (1,2)')
   ->orderBy('number', 'desc')
   ->get();
```

Comment: If I would like to filter by the first letters how could I do? for example.... if I have OE Thing1 and OE Thing2 and I would like to count all OE how could I do?

Comment: @Oscar just use `where('column_name', 'like', "OE%")`

Comment: tanks for answer, that works for count only OE but I want to join all OE in a single count

Comment: for example.. I have some columns with OE and other columns with AE I would like to count OE and AE

Comment: then u need to use `selectRaw("SUM(IF(column LIKE 'OE%' , 1, 0)) AS oe_count")`, something like this...

Comment: I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59843084/how-count-by-the-firest-letters-in-laravel-query-builder