# How count by the first letters in Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I want to make a count by the first letters... I have this column

[image]

I would like to count each OE rows and each GICS rows

I'm working with this query

```
$data4 = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->select(DB::raw('grupo_asig as grupo_asig'), DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
   ->whereNotIn('grupo_asig', [''])
   ->groupBy('grupo_asig')
   ->orderBy('number', 'desc')
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN` and count the field like `OE` and `ASIG`

```php
$data4 = DB::table('incidencias')
           ->select(DB::raw("(CASE WHEN grupo_asig LIKE 'OE%' THEN 'OE'
                                   WHEN grupo_asig LIKE 'GICS%' THEN 'GICS'
                              END) AS grupo_asig_type"), 
                    DB::raw('COUNT(*) as number'))
           ->whereNotIn('grupo_asig', [''])
           ->groupBy('grupo_asig_type')
           ->orderBy('number', 'desc')
           ->get();
```

Comment: I got an error because I'm using an array to make the graphic

Comment: I used this  $array4[] = ['Grupo Asignado', 'Number'];
     foreach($data4 as $key4 => $value4)
     {
      $array4[++$key4] = [$value4->grupo_asig, $value4->number];
     }

Comment: so I got this error Trying to get property 'grupo_asig' of non-object

Comment: @Oscar ok, I am selecting the two value in one record, It seems you want to get the two record and two field(`grupo_asig, number`), and what is the value of `grupo_asig`, if it start with `oe` or `gics`

Comment: Yes, that is that I want to do... I think that the value of grupo_asig is the query of $data4

Comment: @Oscar I have updated it, this one will generate few records according to the `grupo_asig`

Comment: I got this error Undefined property: stdClass::$grupo_asig

Comment: @Oscar because I change it to `grupo_asig_type`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the [LIKE][1] function then and add it to your query:

```
->where('grupo_asig', 'like', 'OE%')
->where('grupo_asig', 'like', 'GICS%')
```

Edit:

I tried a lot around and came to this solution and made a SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06a39b/8

Does it help you?

Comment: that works for count only OE and GICS, but I want to join all OE in a single count and all GICS in another single count

Comment: You want to solve this with one query or a single query?

Comment: one query because I'm using this for a graphic

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `"`, try again?

Comment: Im trying to pass this in an array for a graphic... So I used this code $array4[] = ['Grupo Asignado', 'Number'];
     foreach($data4 as $key4 => $value4)
     {
      $array4[++$key4] = [$value4->grupo_asig, $value4->number];
     } ... and using your method I got this error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$grupo_asig.. you know why? thanks a lot for your help

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Collections. No real need to change your query much.

```php
$data4 = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->select('grupo_asig')
   ->selectRaw('count(*) as number'))
   ->whereNotIn('grupo_asig', [''])
   ->groupBy('grupo_asig')
//   ->orderBy('number', 'desc') Unless you use this array somewhere, it's not needed.
   ->get();
```

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
...

// php >= 7.4.0
$oe_count = $data4->filter(fn($data) => Str::startsWith($data->grupo, 'OE '))->count();
$gigs_count = $data4->filter(fn($data) => Str::startsWith($data->grupo, 'GIGS '))->count();
// php < 7.4.0
$oe_count = $data4->filter(function ($data) {
    return Str::startsWith($data->grupo, 'OE ');
})->count();
$gigs_count = $data4->filter(function ($data) {
    return Str::startsWith($data->grupo, 'GIGS ');
})->count();
```

Starting with Laravel 6, you can also use `cursor()` instead of `get()` in your query to return a LazyCollection. It's faster for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a query for that:

refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10150273/776718)

```sql
SELECT
    LEFT(grupo_asig, 1) AS first_letter,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM incidencias
GROUP BY first_letter
```